# Iterating over a list based on indices in another list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, loops

I have a list of strings - `foo` and another list of integers- `bar` which keeps the track of important indices in `foo`.

For example:

```
foo = [{}.format(i) for i in range(1, 11)] # not necessarily of this format
bar = [0, 3, 5]
```

I would like to create a recipe for creating a list of lists, each list obtained by splitting `foo` based on indices in `bar`.

Expected output for the above example:

```
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5'], ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10']]
```

For achieving this, I have created the following function which works fine:

```
result = []
for index, value in enumerate(b):
    if index == len(b) - 1:
        result.append(a[value:])
    elif index == 0 and value != 0:
        result.append(a[0: value])
    else:
        result.append(a[value: b[index + 1]])
```

However, I find this code highly Non-Pythonic, thanks to my C-Java background.
I would like to know a better solution to this problem (maybe we can use `itertools` somehow).

Comment: Typical slicing problem. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation

Comment: @JanZeiseweis Thank you for the reference but it was of not much use for this particular question.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Thanks for noticing. I will flag it for duplication

Answer (score 2):

You could do as follows:

```
In [3]: [foo[a:b] for a, b in zip(bar, bar[1:]+[None])]
Out[3]: [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5'], ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10']]
```

Comment: If `bar` contains an index equal to the length of `foo` this will generates an empty list! try `bar=[0, 3, 5, 10]`

Comment: A index the length of `foo` would be also be outside the `foo` list?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using a list comprehension:

```
In [107]: bar = bar + [len(foo)] if bar[-1] < len(foo) else bar


In [110]: [foo[i:j] for i, j in zip(bar, bar[1:])]
Out[110]: [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5'], ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10']]
```